# autotools: one project with one executable, one shared obj and a "shared" internal library

Tags: c, autotools, libtool

I am trying my hand at autotools.  I have the following project hierarchy:

```
    project/src
    project/src/utilities
    project/src/utilities/util.c
    project/src/utilities/util.h
    project/src/sharedObject
    project/src/sharedObject/sharedObject.c
    project/src/sharedObject/sharedObject.h
    project/src/sharedObject/thing.c
    project/src/executable
    project/src/executable/exec.c
    project/src/executable/exec.h
    project/src/executable/thing1.c
    project/src/executable/thing2.c
```

`"executable"` and `"sharedObject.so"` both depend on `"util.o"` and `"util.h"`.  I have seen examples of creating convenience libraries but I am not sure how to specify them in the `"Makefile.am"` files in the other two sub-projects.  How are these kinds of inter-project dependencies defined?

Both `"executable"` and `"sharedObject.so"` will be installed.  The `"util.o"` and `"util.h"` files will only be used in the build process.

Thank you

Comment: Before you get too deep into autotools, I recommend taking a look at CMake. I find it a lot easier to work with than autotools. However, if you are making open source software in the traditional style, then autotools is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `utilities/Makefile.am`:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libutil.la   
libutil_la_SOURCES = util.h util.c
```

In `executable/Makefile.am`, the use of the library should use the `LDADD` primary, e.g.,

```
bin_PROGRAMS = exec
exec_SOURCES = exec.h exec.c thing.h thing.c
exec_LDADD = ../utilities/libutil.la
```

In `sharedObject/Makefile.am`, use the `LIBADD` primary:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = sharedObject.la
sharedObject_la_SOURCES = sharedObject.h sharedObject.c thing.c
sharedObject_la_LIBADD = ../utilities/libutil.la
```

If you actually want a `sharedObject.so` that is to be dynamically loaded, you also need:

```
sharedObject_la_LDFLAGS = -module
```

Otherwise, the target should be called `libsharedObject`.

---

The top level Makefile.am should [order](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Subdirectories) `SUBDIRS` so that the dependency is built first:

`SUBDIRS = utilities executable sharedObject`

Comment: Thanks Brett, I will try that in the morning!